# ¿Cómo resolver este error al correr lerna run lint en GitLab?

Tags: yarn, gitlab-ci, eslint, lerna

Tengo un proyecto que de manera local me funciona bien pero al correr el Pipeline en gitlab, me genera un warning con eslin en la fase de `test`; tanto `install` como `build` se generan con éxito pero, al llegar a la fase de `test` me da el siguiente warning:

```
$ lerna run lint
43 info cli using local version of lerna
44 lerna notice cli v3.20.2
45 lerna info ci enabled
46 lerna info Executing command in 7 packages: "yarn run lint"
47 lerna ERR! yarn run lint exited 2 in 'ms-api'
48 lerna ERR! yarn run lint stdout:
49 yarn run v1.22.4
50 $ eslint --ext .ts src/
51 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
52 lerna ERR! yarn run lint stderr:
53 Oops! Something went wrong! :(
54 ESLint: 6.8.0.
55 ESLint couldn't find a configuration file. To set up a configuration file for this project, please run:
56     eslint --init
57 ESLint looked for configuration files in /ruta/__tests__/archivo and its ancestors. If it found none, it then looked in your home directory.
58 If you think you already have a configuration file or if you need more help, please stop by the ESLint chat room: https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint
59 error Command failed with exit code 2.
60 lerna ERR! yarn run lint exited 2 in 'ms-api'
```

Comment: El título de la pregunta no te va a ayudar mucho. Jejejeje, parece klingon.

Comment: jajaja muchas gracias, no sabia que titulo colocar!